# how to use exit or continue handler in mysql function not stored procedure

Tags: mysql, function

I have created one mysql function , this function sometimes throw lock time out exception. I want to handle this exception, here is my function

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getNextNumber;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getNextNumber(key1 VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS INTEGER DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE number INTEGER;
        DECLARE query_timeout INT DEFAULT FALSE;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1205 SET query_timeout = TRUE;
        -- Error: 1205 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT)

        select NUMBER into number FROM NUMBER_TABLE WHERE NUMBER_KEY = key1 FOR UPDATE;

        IF query_timeout = TRUE THEN
            RETURN -1;
        ELSE 
            RETURN (number+1);
        END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I am using FOR UPDATE it locks that table, so if there is lock time out error then I want to return -1 else +1

Comment: The handler will continue the execution after the command that caused the error. So in your case it will do: `select ...-> handler set true -> begin set false end -> if`. I am not sure why you have `set query_timeout = FALSE;` there, but move it infront of your select or remove it (as you already have a default value).

Comment: thanks, I removed  set query_timeout = FALSE;  yes it is not required there, but issue is not resolved.

Comment: On timeout/deadlock, InnoDB rolls back the transaction, which is terminal to execution of a stored function, thus no handlers inside stored function can handle it. 
The only statement that MySQL allows in this case is ROLLBACK, which is not allowed in stored functions anyway. I will handle this through java code.

Comment: @Mohamadsiraj Raza could you please refer me to the documentation that states ROLLBACK is not allowed in a stored function?